# How to get the binary contents of a pandas xlsxwriter object for dropbox upload

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dropbox

I am trying to upload to dropbox an Excel sheet with multiple tabs made with `pandas` and `xlsxwriter`. Not very big files, just around 5MB. I am using the `dropbox` module for Python 3

I am doing:

```
filename = pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx' ,engine='xlsxwriter')
actions.to_excel(filename, sheet_name="Combined Actions")
filename.save()

with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), "/MyAPP/"+filename)
```

I read in the docs that `files_upload` expects a bytes object. I am getting the error: `Type Error: Invalid file: <pandas.io.excel__XlsxWriter object at 0x000000000071C48>`

Is this error because I am not supplying the file in the needed format? How can I do this upload so I don't get a type error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the built in function `open` to open an object. It requires a string as its first argument (which represents a file path). More information on the `open` function can be found in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

The [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e24a8f8886a1481af8324d44224cddb2ee1b53c/pandas/io/excel.py#L754) for pandas ExcelWriter shows it stores the filename you pass to it in `.path`. So renaming your variables to better represent what they are and using the `.path` attribute of the ExcelWriter instance:

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
actions.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="Combined Actions")
excel_file.save()

with open(excel_file.path, 'rb') as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), '/MyAPP/'+excel_file.path)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was definitely a simple mistake. Your solution is correct, also another correct solution would be to just use `myfile.xlsx` instead of `filename` in the `with open...` and in `dbx.files_upload`.